# Apache Kafka: How to send data from different machine

Tags: java, apache-kafka, iot, kafka-producer-api

I started recently studying Apache KAFKA, for IOT application I am working on. Right now, I am having devices which are already sending data to server using HTTP POST and GET.

After struggling a lot for at-least 5-6 hours. I am not able to figure out how we can send data using HTTP POST to Kafka server.

Also, are there any good real life examples present on web which shows detailed configuration of KAFKA cluster that will be really helpful for beginner like me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should know that sending messages with HTTP is suboptimal, compared to Kafka native TCP-based protocol.
But let's say that you know all that and still want to use HTTP.
You need to bring up the Kafka REST Server in order to receive messages over HTTP.

Given that you're still learning, maybe the best course of action would be to use [Confluent's Kafka distribution](http://www.confluent.io/developer#documentation) that comes with the [REST Proxy](http://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/kafka-rest/docs/index.html) and has a great documentation.

BTW Confluent is for Kafka what Datastax is for Cassandra, or Hortonworks/Cloudera is for Hadoop. It's a young company founded by the very creators of Kafka from LinkedIn.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation. Only thing, I was doubtful. How they have made Kafka without inbound HTTP request response lifecycle.